# Schengen tourist visa for a Japanese national

Tags: visas, schengen, uk, netherlands, portugal

I've a Japanese friend coming to the European Union, land in the UK and depart back to Japan from The Netherlands with flights from UK to Portugal and from Portugal to The Netherlands.

I know that Japanese nationals can request a tourist visa on landing but I do not know how it will work when my friend fly from the UK to Portugal and from Portugal to The Netherlands.

What kind of tourist visa does my friend needs to request when landing in the UK to be able to later on leave the UK and entry Portugal and then The Netherlands?

My friend will be staying 4 days in each country, (4 days in the UK, 4 in Portugal and 4 in The Netherlands) but will be attending a conference in the UK. In Portugal and The Netherlands will be solely for tourism.

Comment: According to Timatic, Japanese nationals do not require a visa, or visa on arrival, to enter any of the countries on the itinerary.

Comment: We all love you!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Japanese tourists don't need a visa for either the U.K. or the Schengen Area. They just need to present their passport and itinerary. As long as they can show they're leaving the Schengen Area within 90 days, and the UK within 6 months, and aren't suspected of visa violations, they should be just fine.

Regarding the UK, visa-free nationals who have been refused a visa in the past from any country, violated any immigration rules, or been arrested, may want to apply for a visa ahead of time. But for 99% of visitors from Japan, this is unnecessary.

Comment: (+1) Actually, the advice in the second paragraph applies to the UK (and is in line with official recommendations there) but not to the Schengen area. There are no provisions to issue short-stay visas to visa-exempt nationals, it's just not possible to apply for one.

Answer (score 8):

People often use "visa" to refer to the permission a traveler gets to enter or remain in a country, but in many countries, including those of the EU, a visa is a distinct form of authorization, explicitly not required for certain countries' citizens. Those citizens get an entry stamp in the passport, not a visa. Japan is one of those countries, so its citizens don't need visas to enter EU countries.

This regime applies to stays of up to six months per visit in the UK and up to 90 days in any 180-day period in the Schengen area, so at 4 days and 8 days respectively, your friend isn't even close to the limits.

If you friend *were* required to get a visa, he'd need a UK standard visitor visa plus a short-stay Schengen visa from Portugal covering his time both in Portugal and the Netherlands. There's no passport control between Portugal and the Netherlands, but the airline may check for a visa when the traveler shows a passport that requires one. Again, since a Japanese passport doesn't require one, there will be no problem flying from Portugal to the Netherlands; it's rather like a domestic flight.

Comment: Please would one of the downvoters explain.

Comment: Perhaps some people take issue with the claim that the airline "is likely" to want to check the visa status of passengers on Schengen-internal flights. Airlines _usually_ do not do that; Ryanair is infamous for being an exception.

Comment: @HenningMakholm thanks.  I have softened that to "may check."

Answer (score 5):

Japanese nationals are exempt from visas to visit UK or Schengen countries.

Here is the official source for UK and Schengen states

**1. United Kingdom**

Official source: Check UK visa here: https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa/y/japan/tourism

> **You won’t need a visa to come to the UK**

**2. EU schengen states**

Council Regulation (EC) No 539/2001 of 15 March 2001 listing the third countries whose nationals must be in possession of visas when crossing the external borders and those whose nationals are exempt from that requirement

http://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=CELEX:32001R0539

> Without prejudice to Article 8(2), nationals of third countries on the
>   list in Annex II shall be **exempt** from the requirement set out in
>   paragraph 1, for stays of **no more than three months** in all.
>
> ANNEX II
>
> Common list referred to in Article 1(2)
>
> 1. STATES
>
> Andorra
>
> Argentina
>
> Australia
>
> Bolivia
>
> Brazil
>
> Brunei
>
> Bulgaria
>
> Canada
>
> Chile
>
> Costa Rica
>
> Croatia
>
> Cyprus
>
> Czech Republic
>
> Ecuador
>
> Estonia
>
> Guatemala
>
> Holy See
>
> Honduras
>
> Hungary
>
> Israel
>
> Japan
>
> Latvia
>
> Lithuania
>
> Malaysia
>
> Malta
>
> Mexico
>
> Monaco
>
> New Zealand
>
> Nicaragua
>
> Panama
>
> Paraguay
>
> Poland
>
> Romania(1)
>
> Salvador
>
> San Marino
>
> Singapore
>
> Slovakia
>
> Slovenia
>
> South Korea
>
> Switzerland
>
> United States of America
>
> Uruguay
>
> Venezuela

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. This may help: http://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?qid=1484927622369&uri=CELEX:32016R0399